# Render React SVG component as backgroundImage

Tags: reactjs, svg, jsx

I am trying to render a React Component that returns an `<svg>` as a `backgroundImage` of a `<div>`.
Currently I am using `ReactDOMServer` with `renderToStaticMarkup` or `renderToString` but nothing shows up:

```
const SvgComponent = () => {
    return (
        <svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><rect fill='red' x='0' y='0' /></svg>
    )
}

const ParentComponent = () => {
    return (
        <div
            className={classes.banner}
            style={{
                backgroundImage: `url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8, ${ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(<SvgComponent />)} ")`
            }}
        >
        </div>
    )
}
```

Would the package [jsx-to-string](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsx-to-string) the way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup` uses double quotes in the markup, so it returns

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><rect fill="red" width="10" height="10"></rect></svg>
```

And because you also used double quotes in `url("...")` it gives invalid markup.

So just use single quotes in `url('...')` and it should work.

Note: This will probably break if react changes how `renderToStaticMarkup` is implemented!

Answer (score 4):

You have to use [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) to URI encode the SVG data because React will not render the SVG data if it is not URI encoded. So,

```
const svgString = encodeURIComponent(renderToStaticMarkup(<SvgComponent />));
```

Also, set the width and height in `<rect>` of SVG like,

```
<rect fill="red" width={100} height={100} />
```

So final code should look like,

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { renderToStaticMarkup } from "react-dom/server";
import React from "react";

const SvgComponent = () => {
  return (
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <rect fill="red" width={100} height={100} />
    </svg>
  );
};



const ParentComponent = () => {
const svgString = encodeURIComponent(renderToStaticMarkup(<SvgComponent />));
  return (
      <div
          style={{
              backgroundImage: `url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8, ${svgString}')`,
             width:500,
             height:500
            }}
      >
      </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<ParentComponent />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

I have setup the same in CodeSandbox,

[image: Edit React example]